# MongoDb Conventions IgnorifNullConvention

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a beginner in MongoDb, and I have a problem. If I add a field, for example, firstName. And then query an old document that does not have firstName in it, I get an error message.

"An error occurred while deserializing the UserData property of class Users: No matching creator found."
"stackTrace": " at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap)\r\n...

I tried the mongodb IgnorIfNullConvention, but it does not work and I get the same error.

Do I have to use a different convention or how do I do that?

Comment: Had not problems with such query using mongoose. Could you please add some minimal example of how you exactly query it?

Comment: This problem happens when i query it with graphQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the `IgnoreExtraElementsConvention` convention not the `IgnoreIfNullConvention` one. The `IgnoreIfNullConvention` ignores adding the properties to the BSON document if the property is null. `IgnoreExtraElementsConvention` on the other hand will allow you to have extra fields in your document if the ctor argument value `ignoreExtraElements` is set to true.

```cs
var conventionPack = new ConventionPack()
{
    new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(ignoreExtraElements: true)
};
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreExtraElements", conventionPack, _ => true);
```